# How to insert data into a table from other tables automatically?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a database created with two main tables: User and Series.

- User values: [ username (PK) | password ]
- Serie values: [ name (PK) | chapters ]

I have a relationship which is N:M, where I need to store chapters watched from users, but I don't want to insert manually every user with every serie.

What I need is probably a trigger that can insert a row for every user when I insert a new serie and vice versa.
For example, if I add a new serie (breakingBad) in my Serie table, the next rows need to appear in the relationship between User and Serie:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| username (PK) |  name (PK)  | chaptersWatched |
-------------------------------------------------
|     me235     | breakingBad |        0        |
-------------------------------------------------
|    john23     | breakingBad |        0        |
-------------------------------------------------
  etc..... for every user
```

I'm trying to do it, but I'm newbie with triggers. Something like this is what I'm trying to do:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `serie_before_insert` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `serie` 
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO users_watch_series
VALUES (user.username, serie.name, 0);
```

> Info: DBMS used is MySQL, within PHPMyAdmin, and testing made within HeidiSQL

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a new serie for every user the trigger would look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `serie_before_insert` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `serie` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO users_watch_series
  SELECT user.username, new.name, 0
  FROM user;
END
```

And maybe it's better to define it as `AFTER INSERT` instead of `BEFORE INSERT`.